# Why does Basler GPIO need to have an external powersource + resistor to its GPIO output

Tags: gpio, output, trigger

### Background

We are usingz`Basler camera` with an **output** trigger. The `camera` output `gpio` is 3.3VDC and the `consumer` can handle up to 5V, `logical 1` is above than 2.7V. The camera can output up to 50mili amp max. Out consumer will draw from 3.3v no more than 12 miliamp.

### Questions

#### First

According to the attached diagram, Basler writes that an `external power` source with a resistor is needed. I thought maybe its because the output voltage is `typlical`? Does it mean that the voltage can vary? so the current consumption can be higher?   Or maybe its

#### 2nd

If I do attach external power source then what is the output voltage? (given power source of V and resistor R )?

Thanks
Oak
[image: GPIO output diagram]

Answer (score 2):

Without external power supply you only have 3.3V and 0V logic levels. Which is fine if you're talking to an Arduino or Raspberry pi, but any other industrial controller won't see a logic high at 3.3V, they need at least 10V according to IEC 61131-2.

Hence you connect an external supply in the range you need. And the circuit will operate the same, except the logic high level now is the external supply range.
There will not be any damage due to the diodes inside.

Be aware of the resistor, the output shorts pin 3 and 6 together, this means the resistor is the only element limiting the current.

The industry name for this is "[open collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector)".

Comment: Hey @Jeroen3, so if we have `custom controller`, that works with 3.3V and 0V as logic levels, its OK to work without the external? Does the whole function of the external is to increase the output voltage?